# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list (List problems)

Tags: python, list, pygame, append

Why is it when I try to remove the bubble from the list, it says the bubble is not in the list. At first I had a problem with trying to append a second bubble, but I looked up how to do that. For this problem, I looked up how to solve it and it said to add .copy where my for loops are, but it didnt work. Please help fast and thanks in advance!

```
class Bubble():
  def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.vel = 1
    self.velx = 4
    self.jumpcount = 13
    self.left = False
    self.right = False
    self.walkcount = 0
    self.max = 399
    self.facing = 5

  def drawb(self, win):
    win.blit(ball, (self.x,self.y))

def pop():
  bubbles.append(Bubble(0, 0, 100, 100))

def redrawGameWindow():
  win.blit(background, (0, -150))
  for bullet in bullets:
    bullet.draw3(win)
  for arrow in arrows:
    arrow.draw4(win)
  octo.draw(win)
  for bubble in bubbles:
    b.drawb(win)
  octo2.draw2(win)
  pygame.display.update()

run = True
b = Bubble(0, 0, 64, 64)
octo2 = p2(300, 400, 64, 64)
octo = p1(300, 400, 64, 64)
bullets = []
arrows = []
bubbles = []
if start:
  bubbles.append(Bubble(0, 0, 100, 100))
while run:
  clock.tick(27)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = False

  for bullet in bullets:
    if bullet.y > -100:
      bullet.y -= bullet.vel
      d_x = abs(bullet.x) - abs(b.x)
      d_y = abs(bullet.y) - abs(b.y)
      d = math.sqrt(d_x**2 + d_y**2)
      if d < 50:
        bubbles.remove(Bubble)
        pop()
        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    else:
      bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

  for arrow in arrows:
    if arrow.y > -100:
      arrow.y -= arrow.vel
      d_x = abs(arrow.x) - abs(b.x)
      d_y = abs(arrow.y) - abs(b.y)
      d = math.sqrt(d_x**2 + d_y**2)
      if d < 50:
        bubbles.remove(Bubble)
        pop()
        arrows.pop(arrows.index(arrow))
    else:
      arrows.pop(arrows.index(arrow))
  
  for bubble in bubbles:

    if b.velx >= 9:
      b.velx = 9

    if start:
      b.y += 9
      b.x += 3
      if b.y > 360:
        jump = True
        start = False
    
    if (b.facing == 5):
      direction = 1
    else:
      direction = -1
        
    if b.x > 775:
      b.facing = 0
      grav += 0.15

    if b.x < 0:
      b.facing = 5
      grav += 0.15
      b.velx += 1

    if grav >= 7:
      grav = 7
      b.velx += 1

    if jumpcount >= -15 and jump and b.y < 360:
      b.x += b.velx * direction
      b.y -= ((jumpcount * abs(jumpcount)) * 0.25) / grav
      b.vel -= 1
      jumpcount -= (.5)
    else:
      if b.y >= 361:
        jumpcount = b.jumpcount
        b.y -= (abs((jumpcount * abs(jumpcount)) * 0.25) / grav)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove `Bubble` class and not a specific instance.

Comment: How would I fix it?